# liquibase rollback is not called if patch failed

Tags: java, liquibase

I have patch which is working but rollback method is never called. 
In xml I have:

```
<changeSet id="969" author="sdjulgerova" runAlways="true" failOnError="true">
    <customChange class="com.xxx.xxx.patch.Patch" />
</changeSet>
```

in java I have

```
@Singleton
public class Patch implements CustomTaskChange, CustomTaskRollback {

  @Override
  public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
    // patch logic  
  }

  @Override
  public void rollback(Database database) throws CustomChangeException, RollbackImpossibleException {
    // rollback logic
  }
}
```

rollback() method is never called. No matter if there's an error if execute() and exception is thrown. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto-rollback for 'customChange' tag. http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/custom_change.html

Comment: Generally it can be done manually via command line like `./liquibase [PARAMS] rollback` (see official tutorial for details). As an alternative i would try to create separate class that reverts the custom change (`RollbackPatch implements CustomTaskChange {...}`) and use it in explicit rollback section of your changeset: `<changeSet ...><customChange class="Patch"/><rollback><customChange class="RollbackPatch"/></rollback></changeSet>`